# ¿Es seguro este loop para proteger mi sistema usando php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seguridad

Estoy intentando bloquear un poco los accesos a mi página y ya logré hacerlo por horas usando este script.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Manaus');
  $hInicio = 17;   // Está en 24 hrs
  $hFin = 7;
  $h = date("G");  // Hora actual en 24 hrs
  $realh = (int)$h;
  //se toma la ultima hora de trabajo (las 5pm) para hacer el bloqueo inicial hasta que llegue a las 12
  //luego el bloqueo de fin desde las 0 horas hasta las 7pm hora de inicio  
  // var_dump((int)date("G"));
  if ($realh >= $hInicio && $realh <= $hFin) header("location: bloqueo.html");
```

El primer dato es que el usuario es redirigido a una web que no existe cuando la página web esta fuera de su horario.
Configure mi HTACESS para que cuando hubiera una página web que no conoce lo reenviara al inicio, pero el inicio no puede acceder y es enviado nuevamente al archivo que no existe lo que hace que el HTACCESS vuelva a hacer lo suyo y asi...

Mi duda es :
Es seguro hacer eso?.Puedo intentar a los hackers de este modo tan rebuscado ? 
Gracias por su visita y les agradezco la respuesta .

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer con esto? ¿Qué inseguridad/vulnerabilidad quieres evitar? Ten en cuenta que esto tiene en cuenta la hora del servidor y no la del usuario.

Comment: humildemente, creo que es una perdida de tiempo. No existen horarios seguros, los ataques son constantes. Creo mejor revisas que el firewall funcione correctamente. Dependiendo del servidor y software, puedes poner bloqueos por x cantidad de intentos erroneos, or horarios, etc.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien con que motivo haces eso , es decir , Lo suyo es que si tienes un problema de seguridad en tu web resuelvas el origen del problema.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro evitar cualquier tipo de acceso al sistema. si , lo segundo lo se.

Comment: No es un problema de seguridad lo que tengo @Serux Solo quiero ver que medidas usar para controlar accesos a mi sistema.

Comment: @AlexAngelico podrias tu entrar o vulnerar un sistema que tiene ese loop al momento de ingresar en el ?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la redirección que tienes en .htaccess? ¿Por qué no tener un bloqueo.html para evitar esa redirección infinita? Los servidores y navegadores detectan ese tipo de redirecciones cíclicas y las evitan, pero estarías sobrecargando tu servidor innecesariamente.

Comment: @JuanOrtiz los hackers no se "meten" dentro de tu codigo, buscan cualquier exploit y van ganando privilegios. Si por ejemplo a tu servidor web le falta algún patch, tal vez puedan entrar. O pueden hacer un ataque DDOS, o buscar algun javascript que puedan saltear, etc, etc.

Comment: referido a "hackers" aprovechandose del loop dependerá como esté configurado tu servidor para reaccionar a una alta carga (asumiendo que hay varias redirecciones) el caso de un http flood por ejemplo si la redireccion esta en el htacces y luego hay otra en el php, php va a consumir recursos por cada peticion y si es circular el server puede reaccionar bastante extraño, sin contar que te pueden forzar un log crash (te llenan el disco con logs si no estan configurados para rotar)

Answer (score 0):

Podes probar haciendo la redirección directamente en el .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <07
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >17
RewriteRule ^$ /mantenimiento/fueradehorario.html [R=302,L]
```

arreglado el redirect a temporal (302)

Comment: gracias , pero mi pregunta es si es seguro hacer el loop para evitar accesos.
podria alguien entrar asi con ese loop a mi sistema'? 
Es seguro para el servidor?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro a eso voy , en que tendria problemas al hacerlo asi ?

Comment: habría que ver el .htaccess actual que estas usando, si hay redirecciones finitas o infinitas puede impactar en el servidor

Comment: lo subire en breve. 
tengo un internet muy lento y me cuesta mucho responder.